# Difference betwen these two command lines to execute .jar?

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line, executable-jar

When I execute a .jar with this command line (it's a command found in a script):

```
./MyJar.jar AUTO
```

I have these errors :

```
./MyJar.jar: 1: ./MyJar.jar: PK: not found
./MyJar.jar: 2: ./MyJar.jar:: not found
./MyJar.jar: 3: ./MyJar.jar: ��H: not found
./MyJar.jar: 4: ./MyJar.jar:: not found
./MyJar.jar: 5: ./MyJar.jar: Ant-Version:: not found
./MyJar.jar: 6: ./MyJar.jar: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

But when I execute with this command line, it works:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

1. My first question is : "What's the difference between these two command lines ?"
2. My second question is : "Why am I not able to execute MyJar.jar with the first command line ?"

Comment: Why you don't use google to find how to run jar files?
Jar isn't executable file. It's just java archive and needs java luncher to run. That's why you need java command first.

Comment: Well actually the first command line works on a colleague machine but not on mine. I want to know why. I didn't find anything about the first command on google.

Comment: Read [How to make a JAR file Linux executable](https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable)

Comment: I know how to execute a JAR file. It's just that I want to understand why my colleague can execute it and not me. And I have just found the answer, he had installed the binfmt-support package... 
http://askubuntu.com/a/291514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my second question. To be able to execute my jar this way:

```
./MyJar.jar AUTO
```

I need to install the binfmt-support package :

```
sudo apt-get install binfmt-support
```

As mentionned on this topic : https://askubuntu.com/a/291514

Answer (score 1):

normally if any file trying execute directly by Linux terminal file header information should be identified by OS.
for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Hello World"
```

you can see OS will understand 1st script should be run by /bin/bash interpreter and 2nd is python interpreter.

it seems OS don't under understand how to execute your ./MyJar.jar file.
but jar can directly understand your file content

Comment: Thank you @FariZ for you reply. You answered to my first question!